# Word.application.Selection.Find.Text With multiple Word applications open

Tags: vb.net

I'm having a problem where when I use the `Word.Application.Selection.Find` set of commands, I run into a `NullReferenceException`. In this program I initialize a new Word document as such:

```
Dim wrdApp As Word.application = New Word.Application 
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document = New Word.Document                          
wrdApp.Visible = True

With wrdDoc
    wrdApp.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting()
    wrdApp.Selection.Find.Text = sequenceObject(i, 1, 1, 1).cat
    wrdApp.Selection.Find.Forward = True
    wrdApp.Selection.Find.Wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue
    wrdApp.Selection.Find.Execute
End With
```

When I have no windows open prior to the code running, I have no problem. If I have another word document open at the time, the error occurs at the first `Find` command; it used to occur at the `ClearFormatting` line. I commented it out, then it occurred at the `Find.Text` line. I have the correct object libraries referenced and imported.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I wasn't actually specifying which document to select. By using

```
wrdApp.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow
```

I was able to solve the problem.